# AngularJs - forEach scope array - not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I recognize I am doing something stupid, so please indulge me:**

**Html:**

```html
Filter: <input type="radio" ng-model="Type" value="Rear"> Rear
<input type="radio" ng-model="Type" value="Front"> Front
<br>
Select:
<name-value-select  entry="entry" field="axleType" options="filterTypes"></name-value-select>
```

**Controller:**

```js
$scope.$watch('Type', function (Type) {
    $scope.filterTypes = [];
    if ($scope.axleTypes == undefined || $scope.axleTypes == []) {
        $scope.axleTypes = API.GetAxleTypes;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.axleTypes, function (type) {
        console.log('axleType: ' + type);
        console.log('Type: ' + type);
        if (axleType.Type == Type) {
            this.push(axleType);
        }
    }, $scope.filterTypes);
    $scope.filterTypes.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.Description.localeCompare(b.Description);
    });
});
```

I cannot even loop thru the axleTypes array in my watch function. It appears it is not picking up a collection which is odd because it bypasses populating the axleTypes if undefined or [].

I am doing something so stupid, I can't see it.

**Update: Per Jason's request**

**(1) My angular controller:**

```
$scope.entry = {
    Description: ''
};
$scope.Type = 'Front';
$scope.entry.type = '';

$scope.$watch('Type', function (Type) {
    $scope.filterTypes = [];
    $scope.axleTypes = new API.GetAxleTypes(function (axleTypes) {
        angular.forEach($scope.axleTypes, function (axleType) {
            if (axleType.Type == Type) {
                this.push(axleType);
                }
        }, $scope.filterTypes);
    });

    $scope.filterTypes.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.Description.localeCompare(b.Description);
    });
});
```

**(2)My Html:**

```
Filter: <input type="radio" ng-model="Type" value="Rear"> Rear
<input type="radio" ng-model="Type" value="Front"> Front
<br>
Select:
<name-value-select entry="entry" field="axleType" options="filterTypes"></name-value-select>
```

No more errors Jason, however, when I toggle the two radio buttons nothing happens, ie, Front Axles still show when I choose the Rear axle radio button. Ughh.

Comment: `$scope.axleTypes == []` will never be true. `[] == []` is `false`.

Comment: still, there is the undefined and this is an 'or' situation.

Comment: can you post plunker example? Seems there is a way to do it simplier by angular's internal filters.

Comment: Someone already made one: http://plnkr.co/edit/o51eqq6XjIfAjvdtrz96?p=preview The problem is once I use my API and not use the hard coded array, I get nothing. And I know my API works because above this directive I have:  <select ng-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle" ng-options="axleType.Description for axleType in axleTypes | filterByType: 'Front' | orderBy:'Description'"  id="frontAxles" class="formRequire" required>

Comment: I guess you're using $http.get() for fetching data? In this case check if you're promise-aware - result of .get() is not object/array, but a promise that would be resolved upon request.

Comment: Valentyn: Any chance you could offer a code snippet assuming an API call to the db?

Comment: Scott: Please paste in at least a little bit of the code from API.GetAxleTypes. This could probably be answered pretty quick with just a sample of that code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, cool. I think this is what you want to do. Basically you are loading up your data first, then setting the watch. This way we don't call the async call too many times. I modified the Plunker to use this methodology http://plnkr.co/edit/lQbn4hXmJ1Z4YpKdb4u3?p=preview:

```
$scope.axleTypes = API.GetAxleTypes(function () {
    $scope.$watch('Type', function (Type) {
        $scope.filterTypes = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.axleTypes, function (type) {
            console.log('axleType: ' + type);
            console.log('Type: ' + type);
            if (axleType.Type == Type) {
                this.push(axleType);
            }
            if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$digest();
        }, $scope.filterTypes);
    });
});

$scope.filterTypes.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.Description.localeCompare(b.Description);
});
```

Comment: Jason: See my new updates. I followed your advice and the error is gone, and the initial axles populated in select are correct. But when I choose the Rear axle radio button, the $watch function dos not kick in.

Comment: See edit above. I think you might just be missing a $digest cycle on the callback.

Comment: if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$digest(); did not work and  really do not see why I even needed it, it wasn't in the plkr that had the data hard-codied. [http://plnkr.co/edit/o51eqq6XjIfAjvdtrz96?p=preview]

Comment: Okay, so here's a difference. The sample does not have an async call involved. That is actually why I was saying that you might want to do $scope.$digest() because it wouldn't auto-run after the async call comes back. But there's a better way to handle this. Just make the call one time rather than on each change. I'll edit the example above.

Comment: If you got something that said "Chloe", that was a mistake... my daughter wanted to see what her name looked liked in code. :) I went back to the working version now.